# Polymer-firebase: Firebase query customization

Tags: firebase, polymer

```
<firebase-query
    id="query"
    app-name="notes"
    path="/notes/[[user.uid]]"
    data="{{notes}}">
</firebase-query>
```

Hi, i am new with coding. Anyone help me to customize the code above to show all the notes from all users instead of only current user.uid (that currently login).

//this is the notes app example at [Google Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-firebase-pwa/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#15). I just want to customize that a user can see notes from all other users.

I guess i need to edit the: path="/notes/[[user.uid]]"

But when i change to: path="/notes", no data show up,

Anyone has idea to show data from all users instead of only current logined user in this example, or share me the valid way to edit path if possible?

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of what your problem is and what you're already tried?

Comment: I have just edited my question, anyone know how to edit path element correctly to show data from all users instead of current logined user ?